# MongoDB lookup with multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have got 2 collections and am trying to do a lookup with multiple conditions.

Collection1

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e59c540bb4d036df16808"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id1c1",
  "title": "id1c1 title",
  "type": "type1"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e59da40bb4d036df1680a"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2e3",
  "title": "id2e3 title3",
  "type": "type1"
}]
```

and collection2

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e58c940bb4d036df16801"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2a2",
  "title": "id2a2 title",
  "type": "type1",
  "subarray": [
    {
      "_id": "id2c2",
      "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a2",
      "type": "type1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "id2c4",
      "displayName": "id2c4 for id2a2",
      "type": "type1"
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e58f140bb4d036df16803"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2a3",
  "type": "type1",
  "title": "id2a3 title3",
  "subarray": [
    {
      "_id": "id1c1",
      "displayName": "id1c1 for id2a3",
      "type": "type1"
    },
    {
      "_id": "id2c2",
      "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a3",
      "type": "type1"
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640e590d40bb4d036df16805"
  },
  "myLocalId": "id2a1",
  "type": "type1",
  "title": "id2a1 title",
  "subarray": [
    {
      "_id": "id2c2",
      "type": "type1",
      "displayName": "id2c2 for id2a1"
    }
  ]
}]
```

I have got a basic lookup

```
{
  from: "collection2 ",
  localField: "myLocalId",
  foreignField: "subarray._id",
  as: "result",
}
```

working as expected.

What I want is to do a lookup based on the id and the type as well.

I have tried something like this

```
{
  from: "collection2",
  let: {
    myLocalId: "$myLocalId",
    myType: "$type",
  },
  // Embedded pipeline to control how the join is matched
  pipeline: [
    // Join by two fields in each side
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$subarray._id",
                "$$myLocalId",
              ],
            },
            {
              $eq: [
                "$subarray.type",
                "$$myType",
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  as: "results",
}
```

and I donot see any results.
However when I hardcode ( which will fail for some )

```
{
  from: "myNewCollection",
  let: {
    myLocalId: "$myLocalId",
    myType: "$type",
  },
  // Embedded pipeline to control how the join is matched
  pipeline: [
    // Join by two fields in each side
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $and: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "id1c1",
                "$$myLocalId",
              ],
            },
            {
              $eq: [
                "type1",
                "id1c1",
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  as: "results",
}
```

I get some response.

Could you please let me know what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$in` instead of `$eq` as your `subarray` is an array field.

```js
db.collection1.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      let: {
        myLocalId: "$myLocalId",
        myType: "$type"
      },
      // Embedded pipeline to control how the join is matched
      pipeline: [
        // Join by two fields in each side
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$myLocalId",
                    "$subarray._id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$myType",
                    "$subarray.type"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "results"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ch-DyBQn05D)